# How to Create a Scrollable Survey Overlay in an Android App

Tags: java, android, user-interface, overlay

I've started an Android project that appear on top of other apps but it just show a simple message that appear on top of other apps.

I want to implement it like that type of scrollable view that contains a survey or a series of questions, and when the user clicks on the "Next" button, it automatically scrolls down to the next question without allowing manual scrolling.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.